# How to set the pandas dataframe data left/right alignment?

Tags: python, pandas

I use `pd.set_option("display.colheader_justify","right")` to set the column header. But I can't find the option for data by `pd.describe_option()`.

How to set the data within a dataframe display left or right alignment for each column? Or, is it possible to define a format template for the whole row data display?

Comment: I don't think this exists, by default data is right justified according to the header position there only exists options to format the header not the data as far as I can see

Comment: are you looking to achieve this in the notebook or in general?

Comment: I don't think this exists (I know about some formatting stuff for pivots and Pandas Pretty Tables module), but AFAIK these won't do what you want. If all you need is to print the data, you can use `to_string(justify-'left')` - but this would apply it for all columns. It also seemed that this would work only if your column name is large enough to actually force the entries in the column to be justified. If the column name is small and the entry is large, it won't have any justification effect.

Comment: Most of these answers don't work on the console, for strings, apparently only in Jupyter Notebook (as of pandas 0.25), or for numeric fields. Please make sure to state which.

Comment: This really seems like a missing feature in Pandas / Jupyter, the lengths and struggle involved just to persuade it to display text in a column in a pleasant and readable way.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to change the display in a Jupyter Notebook, you can use the [Style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) feature.

```
# Test data
df = DataFrame({'text': ['foo', 'bar'],
                 'number': [1, 2]})

df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'right'})
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for strings, as can be seen by doing `df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})` with the above example and inspecting the text data column (it will remain right-aligned)

Comment: `{'text-align': 'left'}` seems to work for me now thanks - Pandas 0.22.0, Jupyter 4.4.0, Chrome 70.

Comment: If you want to align the column headers for a single dataframe you can do it by
`df.style.set_table_styles([
                dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'left')] )
            ])`

Comment: To apply to a subset of columns, you can use the subset parameter:
`.set_properties(subset=["col1", "col2"], **{'text-align': 'right'})`.

Comment: I want to clarify that you have to **reassign** the df. The Style command is not done inplace. `df = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})`

Answer (score 24):

The answer given by [@Romain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4413446/romain) is great but I would like to summarize some comments:

```
# Test data
df = DataFrame({'text': ['foo', 'bar'],'number': [1, 2]})

dfStyler = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
dfStyler.set_table_styles([dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'left')])])
```

will align all table text **and** the column headers as well.

Comment: the text is only aligning to the left until 2048, then everything resumes to the right

Answer (score 12):

```
pip3 install tabulate

from tabulate import tabulate
df = pd.DataFrame ({'Text': ['abcdef', 'x'], 'Value': [12.34, 4.2]})
print(tabulate(df, showindex=False, headers=df.columns))

Text      Value
------  -------
abcdef    12.34
x          4.2
```

This will automatically align pandas header and column data to good view format.
Automatically align pandas dataframes columns data to left.
Removes showing of the index in pandas dataframe.
Puts ---- between the header and column data.

Answer (score 9):

Since solutions using [`pandas.Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) don't work in **console printing** (at least for me), I came up with the following code using **pandas 1.3.3** and an example dataframe, printing **all string columns left aligned** (w/o header):

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'float': [0.123, 7],
                       'int': [3, 357676],
                       'str': ["hello world", "bye"],
                       'cat': pd.Series(["a", "bbb"], dtype="category"),
                       'bool': [True, False]
                       })

    formatters = {}
    for col in df.select_dtypes("object"):
        len_max = df[col].str.len().max()
        formatters[col] = lambda _: f"{_:<{len_max}s}"

    print(df.to_string(formatters=formatters))
```

```
       float     int          str  cat   bool
    0  0.123       3  hello world    a   True
    1  7.000  357676  bye          bbb  False
```

---

If you also want to align the header left, add `justify='left'`. For some reason the header is now one character too far to left for *some* columns, but not for all:

```
    print(df.to_string(formatters=formatters, justify="left"))
```

```
       float  int    str          cat   bool 
    0  0.123       3  hello world    a   True
    1  7.000  357676  bye          bbb  False
```

---

However applying this pattern to other dtypes fails (also for string columns). I have no idea why this occurs. Be aware that string conversion is added below via `astype`, also inside the f-string:

```
    formatters = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        len_max = df[col].astype(str).str.len().max()
        formatters[col] = lambda _: f"{_!s:<{len_max}s}"
        print(col, len_max)

    print(df.to_string(formatters=formatters))
```

```
      float    int          str    cat   bool
    0 0.123  3      hello world  a      True 
    1 7.0   357676        bye    bbb    False
```

Comment: `formatters[col] = lambda _: f"{_:<{len_max}s}"` evaluates `len_max` within the f-string not at the time of the function definition but later causing unexpected behavior and your confusion. A workaround this issue is to use:  `eval('lambda x: f"{x:<{'+str(max_len_col)+'}s}"')` which puts the right `max_len` value into the f-string. Now any number of string containing columns can be justified.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of justifying all columns the same way, I had a need to justify some columns differently. Since there was no mention in this thread, I thought of reminding the presence of [the `subset` option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties.html):

```
Styler.set_properties(subset=None, **kwargs)[source]
```

From the same example as the OP, one could left justify just the 'text' column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['foo', 'bar'],
             'number': [1, 2]})
dfStyler = df.style.set_properties(subset=['text'],**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna align both text and header to the left for example you can use:

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'}).set_table_styles([ dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'left')] ) ])
```

This first sets the text to the left and then the header.

Comment: This doesn't work on the console (as of pandas 0.25). Possibly only on Jupyter.

Answer (score 3):

I wrapped [@Hagbard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9805238/hagbard)'s answer in a function to use it whenever I wish to display a pandas dataframe consisting English text on a notebook cell:

```
from pandas import DataFrame


def left_align(df: DataFrame):
    left_aligned_df = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
    left_aligned_df = left_aligned_df.set_table_styles(
        [dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'left')])]
    )
    return left_aligned_df
```

To show a dataframe, I simply write this:

```
left_align(df.head())
```

[image]

*Caution:* For large datasets, it prints all the rows and columns of `df` **without any abstraction**, so Jupyter crashes! That's why I use it with `.head()` or `.tail()` or some other limit.)

Answer (score 2):

you can control it by a new context:

```
with pd.option_context('display.colheader_justify','right'):
    ...
```

Comment: how would you actually apply that to printing out the dataframe? (in Jupyter)

Comment: looks like center aligning headers is not supported, which is a pity

Comment: Is there any option for justifying cells?

Comment: No this only left-aligns the column-headers, not the columns themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I have a class wrapper around my Pandas DataFrame.  This allows me to left-justify the DataFrame's string output by customizing the wrapper's `__str__()` method.

Here's how I solved the problem for my application, based on [Unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25777111/310399) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25777037/310399).  The Pandas DataFrame is referenced by `self.data`:

```
def __str__(self):
    """
    Return the test stats report as a single string
    with left-justified columns.

    """
    # Columns containing boolean values need different format strings
    # to avoid 'ValueError: Invalid format specifier' exceptions.
    BOOL_COLUMNS = ['success',]

    formatters = {}
    for li in list(self.data.columns):
        if li in BOOL_COLUMNS:
            form = "{{!s:<5}}".format()
        else:
            max = self.data[li].str.len().max()
            form = "{{:<{}s}}".format(max)

        formatters[li] = functools.partial(str.format,form)

    return self.data.to_string(formatters=formatters, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions using `style` didn't work for me for left-aligning the text in the headers or cells, for displaying the table in jupyter. And I didn't want to install new libraries just for this

Instead you can get an html representation of the table, change that to specify that all should be left aligned, and display.

Here is a function to do exactly that:

```
import IPython.display

def display_left_aligned_df(df):
    html_table = df.to_html(notebook=True)
    html_table = html_table.replace('<td>', '<td style="text-align:left">').replace('<th>', '<th style="text-align:left">')
    IPython.display.display(IPython.display.HTML(html_table))
```

The `notebook=True` option means the html generated is intended for display in a notebook. So for example length of text in each cell is truncated.

This worked perfectly to generate a jupyter-style table for the dataframe, but left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Also looking to be able to print left-aligned tables to the console/terminal, I accomplished this with a somewhat modified approach from those given:

```py
def whatever_scope():
    ...
    # Closure for the formatter. do whatever fancy formatting you want here.
    def leftalign(len):
        def format(v):
            return(f"{v:<{len}}")
        return(format)

    # create formatters for all columns
    formatters = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        maxlen = df[col].astype(str).str.len().max()
        formatters[col] = leftalign(maxlen)

    # use the formatters
    # remember that `justify` is just for column headers
    text_tbl = df.to_string(
        justify="left",
        formatters=formatters,
        index=False,
    )
    ...
```