# How can I left justify text in a pandas DataFrame column in an IPython notebook

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to format the output in an IPython notebook. I tried using the to_string function, and this neatly lets me eliminate the index column. But the textual data is right justified.

In [10]:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['Text', 'Value']
a = pd.DataFrame ({'Text': ['abcdef', 'x'], 'Value': [12.34, 4.2]})
print (a.to_string (index=False))

   Text  Value
 abcdef  12.34
      x   4.20
```

The same is true when just printing the dataframe.

In [12]:

```
print (a)

     Text  Value
0  abcdef  12.34
1       x   4.20
```

The justify argument in the to_string function, surprisingly, only justifies the column heading.

In [13]:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['Text', 'Value']
a = pd.DataFrame ({'Text': ['abcdef', 'x'], 'Value': [12.34, 4.2]})
print (a.to_string (justify='left', index=False))
Text     Value
 abcdef  12.34
      x   4.20
```

How can I control the justification settings for individual columns?

Comment: As a side note: this is [not currently supported](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4315) for html rendering of data frames either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're willing to use another library, [**tabulate**](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate) will do this -

```
$ pip install tabulate
```

and then

```
from tabulate import tabulate
df = pd.DataFrame ({'Text': ['abcdef', 'x'], 'Value': [12.34, 4.2]})
print(tabulate(df, showindex=False, headers=df.columns))

Text      Value
------  -------
abcdef    12.34
x          4.2
```

It has various other output formats also.

Answer (score 19):

You could use `a['Text'].str.len().max()` to compute the length of the longest string in `a['Text']`, and use that number, `N`, in a left-justified formatter `'{:<Ns}'.format`:

```
In [211]: print(a.to_string(formatters={'Text':'{{:<{}s}}'.format(a['Text'].str.len().max()).format}, index=False))
   Text  Value
 abcdef  12.34
 x        4.20
```

Comment: That is pretty close to what I want. It left aligns the data in the rows of that column, but leaves the column heading "outdented" by a character, at least in this case, when I also use the 'justify' option.

Comment: This is what I want -- thanks. But it's still pretty verbose. I think there should be a simpler way.

Comment: thanks, it's working but it still seems to append an extra space at the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

I like @unutbu's answer (not requiring any additional dependencies). @JS.'s additions are a step in the direction (towards something re-usable).

Since the construction of the formatter dict is the difficult part, let's create a function which creates the formatter dict from a DataFrame and an optional list of columns to format.

```py
def make_lalign_formatter(df, cols=None):
    """
    Construct formatter dict to left-align columns.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
        The DataFrame to format
    cols : None or iterable of strings, optional
        The columns of df to left-align. The default, cols=None, will
        left-align all the columns of dtype object

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        Formatter dictionary

    """
    if cols is None:
       cols = df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'] 

    return {col: f'{{:<{df[col].str.len().max()}s}}'.format for col in cols}
```

Let's create some example data to demonstrate using this function:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Make some data
data = {'First': ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'],
        'Last': ['Thumb', 'Whittington', 'Potter'],
        'Age': [183, 667, 23]}

# Make into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

To align *all* the columns of type object in our DataFrame:

```py
# Left align all columns
print(df.to_string(formatters=make_lalign_formatter(df), 
                   index=False,
                   justify='left'))
```

To align *only* the `'First'` column:

```py
# Left align 'First' column
print(df.to_string(formatters=make_lalign_formatter(df, cols=['First']), 
                   index=False,
                   justify='left'))
```

Comment: Nice function, i found it more handy and reusable though, Only one thing which i see missing is column names are still `outdented`.

Comment: Thanks @kulfi. Yes, I've just noticed this too. It's in using the `justify='left'` argument. I'm not sure if there is a fix for this issue. I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 4):

This works on Python 3.7 (functools is a part of that release now)

```
# pylint: disable=C0103,C0200,R0205
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import functools

@staticmethod
def displayDataFrame(dataframe, displayNumRows=True, displayIndex=True, leftJustify=True):
    # type: (pd.DataFrame, bool, bool, bool) -> None
    """
    :param dataframe: pandas DataFrame
    :param displayNumRows: If True, show the number or rows in the output.
    :param displayIndex: If True, then show the indexes
    :param leftJustify: If True, then use technique to format columns left justified.
    :return: None
    """

    if leftJustify:
        formatters = {}

        for columnName in list(dataframe.columns):
            columnType = type(columnName)  # The magic!!
            # print("{} =>  {}".format(columnName, columnType))
            if columnType == type(bool):
                form = "{{!s:<8}}".format()
            elif columnType == type(float):
                form = "{{!s:<5}}".format()
            else:
                max = dataframe[columnName].str.len().max()
                form = "{{:<{}s}}".format(max)

            formatters[columnName] = functools.partial(str.format, form)

        print(dataframe.to_string(index=displayIndex, formatters=formatters), end="\n\n")
    else:
        print(dataframe.to_string(index=displayIndex), end="\n\n")

    if displayNumRows:
        print("Num Rows: {}".format(len(dataframe)), end="\n\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

I converted @unutbu's approach to a function so I could left-justify my dataframes.

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'StringVals': ["Text string One", "Text string Two", "Text string Three"]})

def left_justified(df):
    formatters = {}
    for li in list(df.columns):
        max = df[li].str.len().max()
        form = "{{:<{}s}}".format(max)
        formatters[li] = functools.partial(str.format, form)
    return df.to_string(formatters=formatters, index=False)
```

So now this:

```
print(my_df.to_string())

          StringVals
0    Text string One
1    Text string Two
2  Text string Three
```

becomes this:

```
print(left_justified(my_df))

StringVals
Text string One  
Text string Two  
Text string Three
```

Note, however, any non-string values in your dataframe will give you errors:

`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

You'll have to pass different format strings to `.to_string()` if you want it to work with non-string values:

```
my_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Booleans'  : [False, True, True],
                       'Floats'    : [1.0, 0.4, 1.5],           
                       'StringVals': ["Text string One", "Text string Two", "Text string Three"]})

FLOAT_COLUMNS = ('Floats',)
BOOLEAN_COLUMNS = ('Booleans',)

def left_justified2(df):
    formatters = {}

    # Pass a custom pattern to format(), based on
    # type of data
    for li in list(df.columns):
        if li in FLOAT_COLUMNS:
           form = "{{!s:<5}}".format()
        elif li in BOOLEAN_COLUMNS:
            form = "{{!s:<8}}".format()
        else:
            max = df[li].str.len().max()
            form = "{{:<{}s}}".format(max)
        formatters[li] = functools.partial(str.format, form)
    return df.to_string(formatters=formatters, index=False)
```

With floats and booleans:

```
print(left_justified2(my_df2))

Booleans Floats         StringVals
False     1.0    Text string One  
True      0.4    Text string Two  
True      1.5    Text string Three
```

Note this approach is a bit of a hack.  Not only do you have to maintain column names in a separate lists, but you also have to best-guess at the data widths.  Perhaps someone with better Pandas-Fu can demonstrate how to automate parsing the dataframe info to generate the formats automatically.