# Python 3.6 Pandas - Left justify data in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

I am trying to left justify the column data in a dataframe when printing it using a bit of a hack of some code I borrowed from another question. It does not appear to be working however in the context I am trying to use it - the `df.stack` line:

```
import pandas as pd

master_list = [['cat', 123, 'yellow'], ['dog', 12345, 'green'], ['horse', 123456, 'red']]

df = pd.DataFrame(master_list)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.colheader_justify','light', 'display.width', 2000, 'display.max_colwidth', 500):
    df = df.stack().str.lstrip().unstack()
    print(df)
```

What do I need to amend? There is no built in option in Pandas to do this in a straightforward manner by the looks of things...

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `df.style`? `df = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232013/how-to-set-the-pandas-dataframe-data-left-right-alignment

Comment: Not sure how this works outside of Jupyter notebooks; seems to play nicer with `display` than `print`.

Comment: hi evan..'df = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})'....gives an output of '<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x0D6BAE10>'

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777037/how-can-i-left-justify-text-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-in-an-ipython-notebook) has a few solutions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(Moving to an answer for easier formatting and readability.)

```
import pandas as pd
master_list = [['cat', 123, 'yellow'], ['dog', 12345, 'green'], ['horse', 123456, 'red']]
df = pd.DataFrame(master_list)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.colheader_justify','light', 'display.width', 2000, 'display.max_colwidth', 500):
    df = df.stack().str.lstrip().unstack()
    df = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
df
```

Edited. However, the output isn't changed; it looks the same as before.

Image of output:
[image]

Comment: how can i use these parameters in your revised code? with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.colheader_justify','light', 'display.width', 2000, 'display.max_colwidth', 500):

Comment: i am still getting the output <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x0D6BAE10>'

Comment: ...your last line...is that meant to be print(df)?

Comment: I use `df` or `display(df)`; let me try something else first, if that's not working for you.

Comment: What environment are you using?

Comment: python3.6...running either in windows batch or just from idle...i'll have to re port it linux eventually, but for now windows based...no anaconda used though...

Comment: Got it. `display` is what I use for Jupyter notebooks. If you need the output via `print`, I'd recommend using one of the solutions from @ALollz's comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183804/discussion-between-evan-and-gdogg371).

Comment: the addition of 'print(tabulate(df, showindex=False, headers=df.columns))
' from the other question solved it in the end...beautiful...thanks for all your help...