# Pandas Tying to left justify a second index after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Here's my code:

```
popular_df = purchase_data_df.groupby(["Item ID", "Item Name"])
popular_df.count()

item_count = popular_df["Item Name"].count()
item_price = popular_df["Price"].mean()
total_pur_val = popular_df["Price"].sum()

popular_item_df = pd.DataFrame({"Purchase Count":item_count,
                                "Item Price":item_price,
                                "Total Purchase Value":total_pur_val
                               })
popular_item_df = popular_item_df.sort_values("Total Purchase Value", ascending=False)
popular_item_df["Item Price"] = popular_item_df["Item Price"].map("${:,.2f}".format)
popular_item_df["Total Purchase Value"] = popular_item_df["Total Purchase Value"].map("${:,.2f}".format)

popular_item_df.head()
```

The output is:

[image: Groupby output]

How can I left justify the '**Item Name**' index, similar to how you'd do in excel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I left justify text in a pandas DataFrame column in an IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777037/how-can-i-left-justify-text-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-in-an-ipython-notebook)

Comment: No it doesn't. I tried that and doesn't work