# How align the pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe where my resulting output columns doesn't aligned correctly as requited and that's  basically a column called `UID` which i need to align `right`.

I have tried Styler but that's not working.

### MY code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
######################
lcmd='ldapsearch -x -LLL -b "ou=Functional,ou=People,ou=dtc,o=dtc"'
result = subprocess.check_output(lcmd, shell=True)
buffer = BytesIO(result)
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = buffer, header=None, names=['LoginShell', 'ExpiryDate', 'UID'])
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split(': ')[-1])
df = df[df.columns[::-1]]
print(df.head())
```

### Result Output:

```
                   UID ExpiryDate LoginShell
0             auto_soc   20991212  /bin/bash
1             sambakul   20991212  /bin/bash
2  services2go-jenkins   20991212  /bin/bash
3              rdtest0   20991212  /bin/bash
4                 sudo   20991212  /bin/bash
```

### What i tried:

```
>>> df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f052c2998d0>

or

>>> df.style.set_properties(subset=["UID", "ExpiryDate", "LoginShell"], **{'text-align': 'left'})
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f052b226fd0>
```

### Expected:

```
                   UID                  ExpiryDate  LoginShell
0                  auto_soc             20991212    /bin/bash
1                  sambakul             20991212    /bin/bash
2                  services2go-jenkins  20991212    /bin/bash
3                  rdtest0              20991212    /bin/bash
4                  sudo                 20991212    /bin/bash
```

### My pandas Version:

```
>>> pd.__version__
'1.1.5'
```

I am using this code on my Linux machine(RedHat7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I left justify text in a pandas DataFrame column in an IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777037/how-can-i-left-justify-text-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-in-an-ipython-notebook)

Comment: this is not about "how can left justify" but how to align your columns with pandas `df.style`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer assumes that all columns are left-aligned. I wrote the code based on the table styles in the [official reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
                   UID ExpiryDate LoginShell
0             auto_soc   20991212  /bin/bash
1             sambakul   20991212  /bin/bash
2  services2go-jenkins   20991212  /bin/bash
3              rdtest0   20991212  /bin/bash
4                 sudo   20991212  /bin/bash
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

from IPython.display import HTML
styles = [dict(selector='td', props=[('text-align','left')])]
html = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)
html
        UID     ExpiryDate  LoginShell
0   auto_soc    20991212    /bin/bash
1   sambakul    20991212    /bin/bash
2   services2go-jenkins     20991212    /bin/bash
3   rdtest0     20991212    /bin/bash
4   sudo    20991212    /bin/bash
```

***I combined it with your code.***

```
from io import BytesIO
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

lcmd='ldapsearch -x -LLL -b "ou=Functional,ou=People,ou=dtc,o=dtc"'
result = subprocess.check_output(lcmd, shell=True)
buffer = BytesIO(result)
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = buffer, header=None, names=['LoginShell', 'ExpiryDate', 'UID'])
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split(': ')[-1])
df = df[df.columns[::-1]]
styles = [dict(selector='td', props=[('text-align','left')])]
html = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)
html
```

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners, how i can align this with my code because these styles i have applied already and giving me `<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7fb864956c18>`

Comment: My code is able to change its appearance in the final output. How do you plan to use it?

Comment: It is not possible to process it as a data frame in its html state. So it can only be used for the final output. If you need to process it after styling, you should use `ljust()`.

Comment: My response was that I wrote the code with the understanding that I wanted to format the output. What is it that you want to do?
Are you asking me to show you how to use `ljust()`?

Comment: NO, ljust() i know, i was just talking about how the approach given by you can be fitted to my situation.

Comment: I understood that the explanation of 'ljust()' was unnecessary. What else can I help you with?

Comment: Hi @r-begnniers , thanks for your support +1 already for that, however as i given the complete code sample , i Just want to use `df.style` in order to get right output. thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Use tabulate to display. below is the code.

```
from io import BytesIO
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

lcmd='ldapsearch -x -LLL -b "ou=Functional,ou=People,ou=dtc,o=dtc"'
result = subprocess.check_output(lcmd, shell=True)
buffer = BytesIO(result)
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = buffer, header=None, names=['LoginShell','ExpiryDate', 'UID'])
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split(': ')[-1])
df = df[df.columns[::-1]]
print(tabulate(df, showindex=False, headers=df.columns))
```

Comment: Vivs, tanks for the answer +1 for the same but this i have tried already, i was Just looking for the usage of df.styler.