# pandas to_string without padding?

Tags: pandas, string, padding, tostring

How can I get the to_string function in pandas to stop padding each line with spaces?

`print(pd.Series(['string', 'another string', 'one more']).to_string(index=False))`

prints

```
         string
 another string
       one more
```

but I would like

```
string
another string
one more
```

Comment: Applying to a Series is slightly different than to a Frame but a number of options also listed here: [How can I left justify text in a pandas DataFrame column in an IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25777037/15497888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the answer to "why pandas doing that" but this may do the work for you:
`print('\n'.join(pd.Series(['string', 'another string', 'one more'])))`

In documentation of `to_string`, pandas says *"Render a string representation of the Series."* As it says "representation", not "equivalent" or something, pandas doing it this way. I'm not sure but I hope it helps.