# How to justify (left) a column of strings in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with several columns. I use Jupyter. One of the columns is just strings, the particular column name is empty ' ':

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[""], [""], [""], ['*'], ['* <<']],
                  columns=[''],
                  index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

print(df)

0    
1    
2    
3   * <<
4      *
```

How can I justify left, so it looks like this:

```
print(df)

0    
1    
2    
3   * <<
4   *
```

Note: if I just use df, instead of print(df), it justifies well.

Comment: Provide `df[''].to_dict()` to reproduce the data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232013/how-to-set-the-pandas-dataframe-data-left-right-alignment

Comment: @Bharathshetty It's not duplicate, I have the opposite problem. Check carefully.

Comment: @hernanavella I dont know why but its aligned to left by default in my kernel. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `pd.Series.str.ljust`

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = (lambda s: s.str.ljust(s.str.len().max()))(df.iloc[:, 0])
df

0      
1      
2      
3  *   
4  * <<
```

Comment: can u elaborate a bit on what [:, 0] does, i'll need to adapt the answer to the real data where the index is different, so I want o know what exactly is that.Thanks.

Comment: Your column header is `''` and I can't grab it with `df["''"]`.  I need the column as a series in order to leverage `pd.Series.str.ljust`.  So to solve the problem of having `''` as a column header, I use positional indexing to grab that first column `df.iloc[:, 0]`