# remove a list of strings from a series of strings

Tags: python, string, pandas

Goal: Remove items from my list, `strings_2_remove`, from a series.
I have a `list` of `strings` like so:

```
strings_2_remove = [
"dogs are so cool",
"cats have cute toe beans"
]
```

I also have a `series` of `strings` that looks like this:

```
df.Sentences.head()

0    dogs are so cool because they are nice and funny 
1    many people love cats because cats have cute toe beans
2    hamsters are very small and furry creatures
3    i got a dog because i know dogs are so cool because they are nice and funny
4    birds are funny when they dance to music, they bop up and down
Name: Summary, dtype: object
```

The outcome after removing the `strings` in the `list` from the `series` should look like this:

```
    0    because they are nice and funny 
    1    many people love cats because 
    2    hamsters are very small and furry creatures
    3    i got a dog because i know because they are nice and funny
    4    birds are funny when they dance to music, they bop up and down
    Name: Summary, dtype: object
```

I have the following in attempt to achieve the output I want:

```
mask_1 = (df.Sentences == strings_2_remove)
df.loc[mask_1, 'df.Sentences'] = " "
```

However, it is not achieving my goal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
result = df.Sentences
for stringToRemove in strings_2_remove:
    result = result.replace(stringToRemove, '', regex=False)
```

There are better, more performant solutions using RegEx. More information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
df.Sentences.apply(lambda x: re.sub('|'.join(strings_2_remove),'',x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df.Sentences.replace('|'.join(strings_2_remove), '', regex=True)

0                      because they are nice and funny
1                       many people love cats because 
2          hamsters are very small and furry creatures
3    i got a dog because i know  because they are n...
4    birds are funny when they dance to music, they...
Name: Sentences, dtype: object
```

Comment: hey do you know the cause of this unsynchronized strings ? i got the same output

Comment: It's just pandas display settings - default is right-aligned. There is no whitespace padding or anything

Comment: about whitespace i knew that.. hmm how can i change this for a better display ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232013/how-to-set-the-pandas-dataframe-data-left-right-alignment

Comment: back at you buddy

Answer (score 0):

I created the test Dataframe as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Summary':[
    'dogs are so cool because they are nice and funny',
    'many people love cats because cats have cute toe beans',
    'hamsters are very small and furry creatures',
    'i got a dog because i know dogs are so cool because they are nice and funny',
    'birds are funny when they dance to music, they bop up and down']})
```

The first step is to convert your `strings_2_remove` to a list of patterns
(you have to `import re`):

```
pats = [ re.compile(str + ' *') for str in strings_2_remove ]
```

Note that each pattern is supplemented with `' *'` - an optional space.
Otherwise the result string could contain **two** adjacent spaces.
As I see, other solution missed on this detail.

Then define a function to be applied:

```
def fn(txt):
    for pat in pats:
        if pat.search(txt):
            return pat.sub('', txt)
    return txt
```

For each pattern it searches the source string and if something has been
found then returns the result of substitution
of the matched string with an empty string.
Otherwise it returns the source string.

And the only thing to do is to apply this function:

```
df.Summary.apply(fn)
```