# Having a problem viewing dataframes in Colab

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to view sklearn data sets as Pandas dataframes inside a Colab notebook.

Through someone else's suggestion, I've found the command

```
%load_ext google.colab.data_table
```

very helpful. For example, the following code is for loading and viewing the well-known wine data set

```
import pandas as pd
%load_ext google.colab.data_table
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
data = load_wine()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['feature_names'])
df['target'] = data['target']
df
```

In the results cell I have the option to select how many rows I wish to view on one page. It's really nice for navigating through the data.

Then I tried the same thing with the Wisconsin breast cancer data:

```
import pandas as pd
%load_ext google.colab.data_table
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
data = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['feature_names'])
df['target'] = data['target']
df
```

Now, there is no such option to select how many rows I wish to view on one page.

I'm curious to know if different outcomes might be related to any different formats in the particular sklearn data sets.

Comment: Are you using jupyter?

Comment: No, it's in a Google Colab notebook. While I've used Jupyter in my own work, this is being used for teaching purposes in a linear algebra course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the number of rows displayed in colab (or any other shell/IDE) by using the ".head(n)" method for pandas dataframes, where n is the number of rows you would like displayed. In order to view all displayed rows set 'display.max_rows' to None. The below
displays the first 40 rows in the breast cancer dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)   

data = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['feature_names'])
df['target'] = data['target']
df.head(40)
```

While the breast cancer dataset does not have the interactive pull down "show per page" tab this should suffice to allow you to see all rows you would like in a DataFrame.

Comment: Any chance you know of a way to make the data appear centered in each column?

Comment: Please have a look at this thread; [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232013/how-to-set-the-pandas-dataframe-data-left-right-alignment). Just change 'rightt' to 'center'