# How to align table text in a code line in JupiterNotebook?

Tags: python

I have created a summary table by concatenating columns and the default alignment is to the left. How can I change that to the right or center?

```
pd.concat([flights_raw.dtypes,flights_raw.count(),flights_raw.isnull().sum(), round(100 * flights_raw.isnull().sum()/len(flights_raw),2)], 
              axis=1).rename(columns={0:'Dtype',1:'Non-null count',2:'Missing #',3:'Missing (%)'})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TqJ0.png)

Comment: The code you show only does a calculation. How are you outputing the table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the pandas dataframe data left/right alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232013/how-to-set-the-pandas-dataframe-data-left-right-alignment)

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help! I am truly impressed by the fact that people take their time to answer questions!
I am using Jupiter notebook and the output is inserted right below the code line. The attached image shows the output. 
@TYZ. Thank you for the forward!