# Python - DataFrame - Left Justify Columns

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to left justify the columns in the code below. The sample data is below which is in a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

pd.set_option('display.width', 400)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
today = datetime.date.strftime(datetime.date.today(), "%m/%d/%Y")

rr_df = pd.read_csv("/mac/dev/py/mfo/mfovenv/data/rr.csv", parse_dates=["DATE"], index_col="DATE", na_values=['no info', '.'])
rr_df.drop(["TEMP"], axis=1, inplace=True)
rr_df = rr_df.reindex(columns=['SYMBOL', 'INDEX', 'BUY TRADE', 'SELL TRADE', 'PREV. CLOSE', 'TREND', 'DOWNSIDE', 'UPSIDE', 'U/D'])

# Style - Color for Bearish / Bullish / Neutral Trend
def cts(x):
    c1 = "color: green"
    c2 = "color: red"
    c3 = "color: gray"
    if "BULLISH" in x["TREND"]:
        return c1, c1, c1
    elif "BEARISH" in x["TREND"]:
        return c2, c2, c2
    elif "NEUTRAL" in x["TREND"]:
        return c3,c3, c3
    else:
        return c3, c3, c3


rr_df.loc[today].reset_index().style.apply(cts, subset=["BUY TRADE", "SELL TRADE", "TREND"], axis=1)

rr_df.to_string(formatters=make_lalign_formatter(rr_df), index=False, justify='left')
```

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m8wh.png)

Chris adding the code below didn't do anything

rr_df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})

[Chris Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfyg3.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the pandas dataframe data left/right alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232013/how-to-set-the-pandas-dataframe-data-left-right-alignment)

Comment: No it didn't do anything. See screenshot above.