# Pandas styling border to all columns and headings aligned to center

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I have a pandas data frame for which I need to add borders to all columns and column headings needs to come in the center.

Below is my code.I obtained the code stack overflow itself.After running the code the borders are coming to all columns but the colors of each row is differnt.Please see the below image.

May I know how to solve this issue and make all rows same color and column headings aligned to center.

Please see my code and table below.

```
summary_FR =pd.concat([Chip_Cur_Summary_funct_mode2,Noise_Summary_funct_mode2,VCM_Summary_funct_mode2,Sens_Summary_funct_mode2,Vbias_Summary_funct_mode2,vcm_delta_Summary_funct_mode2,THD_FUN_M2,F_LOW_FUNC_Summary_mode2,OSC_FUNC_Summary_mode2,FOSC_FUNC_Summary_mode2,VREF_CP_FUNC_Summary_mode2,Summary_PSRR_1KHz_funct_mode2,Summary_PSRR_20Hzto20KHz_funct_mode2,Output_Impedance_FUNC_Summary_mode2,Output_Impedance_Freq_FUNC_Summary_mode2])
# summary_FR
summary_FR.style.set_table_styles(
    [{"selector": "", "props": [("border", "1px solid grey")]},
      {"selector": "tbody td", "props": [("border", "1px solid grey")]},
     {"selector": "th", "props": [("border", "1px solid grey")]}
    ]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the pandas dataframe data left/right alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232013/how-to-set-the-pandas-dataframe-data-left-right-alignment)

Comment: That looks like a Jupyter Notebook display. Jupyter Notebook defines its own CSS which detects pandas dataframes and colors rows in odd/even colors. If you print the HTML output from the Styler and open it in a regular web browser those white/grey rows will not be visible, since a web browser only displays the underling HTML with no extras.