# How can I fix the alignment of the content to left after reading csv file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fix the alignment of the content to left in pandas, but it does not let me.
I have the table like this :

```
   Name           DKP    LT   
1          NAME1  13150  13150
2          NAME2  12000  12000
3          NAME3   8373   8373
4          NAME4   4912   4912
5          NAME5   3433   3433
```

and I want it to be like this:

```
   Name           DKP    LT   
1  NAME1          13150  13150
2  NAME2          12000  12000
3  NAME3          8373   8373
4  NAME4          4912   4912
5  NAME5          3433   3433
```

The code is ( I use that on discord.py bot on repilt.com ):

```
  import csv , operator , math
  import pandas as pd
  data = pd.read_csv("resDKP.csv",delimiter = ",",index_col=False)
  data = data.sort_values(by=['DKP'],ascending=False)
  data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
  data.index = data.index + 1
  pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'left')
  print(data)
```

Comment: are there any whitespace characters to the left of the name? where are you seeing it? Jupyter notebook, which tool?

Comment: does that answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232013/how-to-set-the-pandas-dataframe-data-left-right-alignment

Comment: I'm seeing it at repilt.com

Comment: Can you show a sample of the resDKP.csv?

Comment: Name,DKP,LT (new line) NAME1,13150,13150  NAME2,12000,12000

Comment: This question does not seem to pertain to [tag:discord.py], the tag should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = data.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

Comment: I tried
data = data.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
but i can print in repilt.com